# Vanilla Javascript multiple same selects, when you select 1 option, all other selects change to the same option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

if we have for example 3 same selects in the same page, but on different parts of the page

```html
<div>
<select>
    <option value="london">London</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <p> hello </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p> This is a random sentence </p>
</div>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
<div>
  <p> Bye </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p> This is a random second sentence </p>
</div>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
```

I want that if i select for example 2 in the first select the other 2 selects change to option value="two" too.
Is this possible?
Thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? What is your attempt to solve this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delegate.

Change container to the nearest static container holding all selects or wrap them

Here I gave the selects I want to sync a class

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll("select.sync");
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("sync")) {
    const idx = tgt.selectedIndex;
    selects.forEach(sel => sel.selectedIndex = idx);
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="london">London</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="sync">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <p> hello </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p> This is a random sentence </p>
</div>
<select class="sync">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
  <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
<div>
  <p> Bye </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p> This is a random second sentence </p>
</div>
<select class="sync">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
  <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), the issue is that the selects are not in the same part of the page and i have other selects in the page, ill try to explain myself better in the first post

Comment: @lordf if the selects are all in the same page this will work fine.

Comment: @LelioFaieta i know but i have other selects in the same page :S, i forgot to add this important information, sorry

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, i added a class for the selects and a class for the  querySelectorAll and it works

Comment: See updated code which will only synchronise selects with class="sync"